# oracle db column date default value not sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle

how to set the default value for a date column for something diferent that sysdate? like 01/07/1998, im currently using

```
ALTER TABLE XILIADO 
ADD (FECHA_AFIL DATE DEFAULT sysdate NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a fixed date, either with `to_date()` with a string literal and matching format model, or a date literal:

```
ALTER TABLE XILIADO 
ADD (FECHA_AFIL DATE DEFAULT DATE '1998-07-01' NOT NULL);
```

(assuming your example was in DD/MM/YYYY format; date literals are unambiguous, which is another advantage of using them.)

Answer (score 3):

For any fixed date, use to_date(date_value, date_mask) along with alter column.

```
ALTER TABLE XILIADO
ADD FECHA_AFIL DATE DEFAULT TO_DATE('01-07-1998','DD-MM-YYYY') NOT NULL
```